# PHP/SOAP Uncaught SoapFault exception: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, class, object, soap

I'm trying to make a very small SOAP system working, but I'm struggling with a (small) problem for a few days and Google couldn't help me neither...

What I want to do: I want to do some things on a few variables, which I'm passing in a class. 
Problem: I want to use the incoming class on my server.php file as an Object. But that's not possible.

My server PHP file:

```
class Lid
{
    public $NumberOfYears; //this one is public for example purpose only
    private $tew;
    private $School;
    private $Price;

    public function __construct($dump){
        $this->tew = "dump:".$dump;
    }

    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->Price;
    }
}
class Functies{
    public function __construct(Lid $Lid){
            $Lid->getPrice();   //What I want to do
        return new Lid($Lid->NumberOfYears);
    }
}

$classmap = array('Lid'=>'Lid');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL,
    array(
        'classmap'=>$classmap, 
            'uri' => "http://127.0.0.1/ns/soap/")
    );
$server->setClass("Functies");
$server->handle();
```

The class "Functies" has all the methods I want to export via SOAP. I'm using the transport class Lid as an Argument. What I actually want to do is calling methods on the incoming class $Lid.
When I try to run the client script, it is returning the following error:
`Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to undefined method stdClass::getPrice()`

I understand the problem. PHP thinks that the argument $Lid is a class, and not an object.

So, my questions:

1. How can I make $Lid an object?
2. How can I access my private / public variables? I tried to do this via `$Lid->NumberOfYears` but that's just returning an empty string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

About two years ago, I've tried to do something really close to what you are attempting here.

Since those days, I use SOAP as less as possible.

In fact, SOAP works quite well (I say "quite" because of the obscure, redundant and verbose WSDL definition, and for the awful, unclear error messages of the PHP SOAP library), for **very simple data structures** (associative arrays being the "best" I've been able to use without problem if I remember well).

As soon as I wanted to "share" a full class with methods, advanced properties etc. between a client and server, it was simply impossible to reach my goal (e.g. unable to execute a method on a transferred object).

So I gave up that idea before taking too much time and headache on it, and made all that was possible to transfer data having only **simple structures** through SOAP...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting a few more days waiting for more replies I just gave up.

My solution: if PHP isn't making an object for me, I will make it on my own.

So instead of exporting the class "Functies" I just created an extra class (functiesNew), with the same methods, but with normal variables as input (using simple data structures as the person above was saying).

```
class functiesNew{
public function methodX($array){
    $Lid = new Lid();
    foreach($array as $name => $value){
        //fill the Lid object
    }

    // call the method we wanted to call from the beginning
    new Functies($Lid);
}   
}
```